# JPanel array display only last panel in array

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I created a array of JPanels which contains a common JLabel

```
class gui 
{

    JPanel[] multpanel;
    JPanel finalPane = new JPanel();
    JLabel InputLabel = new JLabel("Input Files");
    
    gui()
    {
        InputLabel.setLocation(50,50);
        InputLabel.setSize(120,20);
        int total_instances=2;
        multpanel=new JPanel[total_instances];

        for(int instance=0;instance<total_instances;instance++)
        {
            multpanel[instance]=new JPanel();
            multpanel[instance].setLocation(10,0);
            multpanel[instance].setSize(500,500);
            multpanel[instance].setLayout(null);
            multpanel[instance].add(InputLabel);
        }

        finalPane.add(multpanel[0]);
        finalPane.add(multpanel[1]);
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(finalPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

this a short version of my program, i creating array of panels and at a time only one panel is visible
My problem is that it only display last panel in array, in my case 2nd panel of array is displayed and when i try to display first panel it displays nothing

like if i have panel array of size five then only 5th panel is displayed and all other panels display blank

Is this because i am adding a common label in it

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A given component may only have one ancestor. So, when you add a label to a panel, you're effectively removing it from the previous one. If you want a label in 5 panels, you need 5 labels.

Two additional notes:

- you should learn Java naming conventions and stick to them. Variables start with a lower-case letter and classes with an upper-case letter.
- you should learn to use layout managers. That's the proper way to lay out components. Don't set the layout to null.

Comment: ok thanks, i know java naming conventions and i always stick to them, its not a copy paste code, i write this here so i forgot about naming conventions. I am trying java swing first time thats why i don't have much knowledge of layout manager. thanks for your help

Comment: ok one more question i create a array of 5 Jtextfield and one normal Jtextfield textField, i assign each array element equal to textField and add it to panel array declared above, still it display it in last panel array. Why this is happening this time i declared 5 Jtextfield but all are equal to same textField

Comment: When you add an object to an array, you don't create a copy of the object. You just store a reference (a pointer if you prefer) to the object. So you have 5 references to the same JTextField object. If you want 5 text fields, you need to call new JTextField() 5 times, to have 5 objects, and not just 5 references to 1 object.

Answer (score 2):

Use proper LayoutManager e.g. BoxLayout and don't set size and location of the panels.
`setLayout(null);` <-- would not recomment to use that.